# org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher : exception clearing maxRows/queryTimeout

Tags: sql-server, tomcat

I am getting the below exception when my application tries to query MS SQL server for a functionality.
Referring to other suggestions on this forum, I have already updated my tomcat configuration (context.xml) for the impacted resource to values shown below.
But it didn't help.
An observation on this, if the functionality is repeatedly invoked, then it works in 1 out of 4/5 attempts.
Also, when it works, the specific item it fails other time is executed within 40 seconds. (Usually 36-39 seconds)
However, if at all it touches the 40 seconds mark, the exception is thrown and functionality fails.

**Resource Config**

```
<Resource
    minEvictableIdleTimeMillis="60000"
    maxActive="100"
    auth="Container"
    testOnBorrow="true"
    password="*******" 
    testOnReturn="false"
    testWhileIdle="true" 
    url="jdbc:sqlserver://*****"
    maxWait="10000"
    maxIdle="30"
    name="jdbc/CiteMod"
    username="********" 
    driverClassName="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" 
    type="javax.sql.DataSource"
    validationQuery="Select 1"
    timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis="1800000">
```

**Exception Log**

```
15:25:15.259(07/11) WARN  org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher : exception clearing maxRows/queryTimeout
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The connection is closed.
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(SQLServerException.java:190)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.checkClosed(SQLServerConnection.java:388)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.checkClosed(SQLServerStatement.java:978)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.getMaxRows(SQLServerStatement.java:1011)
        at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.DelegatingStatement.getMaxRows(DelegatingStatement.java:237)
        at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.DelegatingStatement.getMaxRows(DelegatingStatement.java:237)
        at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.closeQueryStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:298)
        at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.closeQueryStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:234)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:1863)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:718)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:270)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2294)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2172)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2167)
        at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.list(CustomLoader.java:316)
        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.listCustomQuery(SessionImpl.java:1832)
        at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.list(AbstractSessionImpl.java:165)
        at org.hibernate.impl.SQLQueryImpl.list(SQLQueryImpl.java:179)
        at com.lexisnexis.citemod.metadata.service.ExportFilesService.verifyTokenizeResolutionFileName(ExportFilesService.java:594)
        at com.lexisnexis.citemod.metadata.service.ExportFilesService.verifyTokenizeResolutionFile(ExportFilesService.java:551)
        at com.lexisnexis.citemod.metadata.web.action.export.ExportFilesAction.listVerifyTokenizeResolution(ExportFilesAction.java:496)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor402.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.struts.actions.DispatchAction.dispatchMethod(DispatchAction.java:269)
        at org.apache.struts.actions.DispatchAction.execute(DispatchAction.java:170)
        at org.apache.struts.actions.LookupDispatchAction.execute(LookupDispatchAction.java:146)
        at org.apache.struts.chain.commands.servlet.ExecuteAction.execute(ExecuteAction.java:58)
        at org.apache.struts.chain.commands.AbstractExecuteAction.execute(AbstractExecuteAction.java:67)
        at org.apache.struts.chain.commands.ActionCommandBase.execute(ActionCommandBase.java:51)
        at org.apache.commons.chain.impl.ChainBase.execute(ChainBase.java:191)
        at org.apache.commons.chain.generic.LookupCommand.execute(LookupCommand.java:305)
        at org.apache.commons.chain.impl.ChainBase.execute(ChainBase.java:191)
        at org.apache.struts.chain.ComposableRequestProcessor.process(ComposableRequestProcessor.java:283)
        at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1913)
        at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:462)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
:
```

Comment: Update: I tried replacing the hibernate code to connect the database with simple JDBC connection (To rule out any possibility of timeout due to hibernate defaults) 
However, still getting the Connection reset exception!  And yet again- Just at the 40seconds mark!
Any thoughts?

Comment: While I got this working long back, missed updating it here.
Just in case someone is stuck up with this, I don't know the root cause but this got me working-
I read about a windows parameter called 'TCPChimneyTimeout' which has something to do with the 40 sec timeout.
So, I asked my DBA to check the value of this parameter on the server where my DB was hosted. 
Although the flag was set to expected value which is Off - (if I remember correctly)-; but just the DBA logging into that server seemed to solved it.
Didn't get that error yet.